# How to kill multiple Docker containers of an image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Once in a while I bash into my containers to manually run some scripts on my servers and sometimes my session times out and those containers stay up.
I'm trying to run a command to kill all previous running containers of that image. Let's say my image is called "WEB" and this is what `docker ps` is showing:

`ID          NAMES 
 1          project_web_1
 2          project_web_2
 3          project_web_3`

I want to kill all of those with a single command. I have tried this
`docker rm -f $(docker ps -aqf "name=web")` but this only kills the first one. Is there a way to kill all of them?

Comment: `docker rmi $(docker images | grep 'web')` does this work?

Comment: @TuğberkKaanDuman actually it seems my commands works I just had a typo in my image name. I tried yours and it didn't work

Comment: Nice to know that you managed to solve it, wish I could help. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems my command actually removes all of them

`docker rm -f $(docker ps -aqf "name=web")`

I just had a typo in my image name. I leave this question/answer in case someone in the future needs it.

Answer (score 0):

`docker container rm -f $(docker container ps | awk '/yourname/ {print $1}')`
Replace `yourname` with the name or anything you want to match from `docker ps`.